# "attempted to dereference a scalar variable" when array value is not provided

Tags: coldfusion

I have run into an issue when I try running get the array elements. This is a weather feed and sometimes they have expiration times and others they do not. So for example if there is an update to a weather event, they may not provide a expiration time.I have researched and found that most the posts say to use ArrayIsDefined.

However I tried that:

```
<cfif ArrayIsDefined(myArrayObj.properties.ends, [i])>Expires: #myArrayObj[i].properties.ends#<br></cfif>
```

but it keeps producing the following error:

```
You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members. The error occurred on line 45.
```

But when there is a value, no problem. I check the code against what others have suggested and I believe I am doing it properly.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
 <strong>NOAA Feed:</strong> #myArrayObj[i].properties.event#<br></strong>
      Effective: #myArrayObj[i].properties.effective#<br>
      <cfif ArrayIsDefined(myArrayObj.properties.ends, [i])>Expires:     #myArrayObj[i].properties.ends#<br></cfif>
 
      ID: #myArrayObj[i].id#<br>
      Headline: #myArrayObj[i].properties.headline#<br>
      Area: #myArrayObj[i].properties.areaDesc#<br>
      Type: #myArrayObj[i].properties.messageType#<br>
      Description: #myArrayObj[i].properties.description#<br>
      <!------>Area: #myArrayObj[i].geometry.type#<br>
      <!------>
       <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(myArrayObj[i].geometry.coordinates[1])#" index="d">
       <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(myArrayObj[i].geometry.coordinates[1][d])#" index="g">
            #myArrayObj[i].geometry.coordinates[1][d][g]#
         </cfloop>,&nbsp;
         </cfloop>
```

Comment: The `isArray()` function might be more appropriate than `arrayIsDefined()`.

Comment: Thanks Dan.... I tried that and got the same error. Here is what I am putting in: <cfif isArray(myArrayObj.properties.ends, [i])>Expires: #myArrayObj[i].properties.ends#<br></cfif> Am I doing it wrong? I think its right. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the error again: Element PROPERTIES.ENDS is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression

Comment: Also tried <cfif isArray(myArrayObj[i].properties.ends)>Expires: #myArrayObj[i].properties.ends#<br></cfif>

Comment: What does this `myArrayObj.properties.ends` look like? Are we sure that's an array?

Comment: Index should just be a number, not in square brackets: `ArrayIsDefined(myArrayObj.properties.ends, i)`

Answer (score 2):

A combination of isDefined and isArray should do it?

```
<cfif IsDefined("myArrayObj.properties.ends") AND isArray(myArrayObj.properties.ends)>
```

Next, if the object is an array, you can't output it like this: #myArrayObj[i].properties.ends#.  Perhaps now check for the element in the array?

```
<cfif IsDefined("myArrayObj.properties.ends") AND isArray(myArrayObj.properties.ends) AND arrayIsDefined(myArrayObj.properties.ends,1)>
    #myArrayObj.properties.ends[1]#
</cfif>
```

Whenever I work with JSON APIs like this, my IF statements are a mile long verifying everything is where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Once again..... that worked perfectly! Thank you all for your great knowledge!